# Как получить доступ к словарю из другого файла python

Tags: python

Сначала запускаю file_1.
Словарь создан и заполнен в file_1, печатается из этого файла заполненным объектами MyClass.
Затем запускаю file_3.
Из file_3 печатается пустой словарь, т.е. просто скобки.
Как получить доступ к my_dict из file_1 ?

Код примерно такой:

#file_1:

```
import file_2
my_dict = {}    
async def main():    
    global my_dict
    for key in range(10):
        my_dict.update({key: MyClass})

print('file_1', my_dict)
```

#file_2:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
```

#file_3

```
import file_1    

print('file_3', file_1.my_dict)
```

вывод из file_1

```
>>> file_1 {'...Заполненный словарь...'}
```

вывод из file_3

```
>>> file_3 {}
```

Comment: в `file_1` вы заполняете `my_dict` через функцию `async def main()`. А в каком месте вы его вызываете? Можно [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Павел файл1 не прекращает выполнятся, он в цикле крутится

Comment: @Олег для ваших целей больше подойдет запись в файлы в ОС, у вас немного неверное представление по поводу глобальных переменных

Comment: Я через словарь обращаюсь к экземплярам MyClass. Писать/читать файл долго будет, наверное. Из файла 3 мне в принципе нужно только одну переменную менять. Попробую через функцию

Comment: Не получилось... Я делал словарь т.к. имя экземпляра класса - строка. А как создать экземпляр класса, если имя - строка?